# Transfer ownership of google drive of deleted user?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I want to transfer the ownership of google drive of deleted user, using google workspace API. I was able to undelete a user using google API(so i assume their google drive will also be restored).

```
https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/107598164438125043533/undelete
```

How to transfer the ownership of that user's drive to someone in my organisation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at the [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer)

The Data Transfer API manages the transfer of data from one user to another within a domain. The user receiving the data must belong to your domain.

[Transfer data](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/transfer-data)

```
{
  "oldOwnerUserId": "SOURCE_USER_ID",
  "newOwnerUserId": "DESTINATION_USER_ID",
  "applicationDataTransfers": [
    {
      "applicationId": "435070579839",
      "applicationTransferParams": [
        {
          "key": "RELEASE_RESOURCES",
          "value": [
            "TRUE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this seems very high level, could you help me to understand how to do use this API using nodejs code.